# php and mysql - Send checkbox, radio button, and drop down menu results from user to mysql database and store it there

Tags: php, mysql, drop-down-menu, checkbox, radio-button

I am trying to have my form data stored in a mysql database. I want everything that the user types or clicks to be stored there. I am able to have my text fields stored in mysql successfully. I am having trouble figuring out how to send multiple check boxes, radio buttons, and drop down lists to mysql and have it stored there. I don't even know where to begin. Please help.

```
CREATE TABLE wer(
ID int NOT NULL auto_increment,
student_gender varchar(6),
student_session_one_preference varchar(30),
student_session_two_preference varchar(30),
waldron_scholarship tinyint,
jesse_van_anterp_huyck_scholarship tinyint,
edward_raney_scholarship tinyint,
school_type varchar(25),
student_statemenet_consent_check_box tinyint,
guardian_statemenet_consent_check_box tinyint,
waiver tinyint, 
PRIMARY KEY(ID)
);



$student_gender = trim(mysql_prep($_POST['student_gender']));
$student_session_one_preference = trim(mysql_prep($_POST['student_session_one_preference']));
$student_session_two_preference = trim(mysql_prep($_POST['student_session_two_preference']));
$waldron_scholarship = trim(mysql_prep($_POST['waldron_scholarship']));
$jesse_van_anterp_huyck_scholarship = trim(mysql_prep($_POST['jesse_van_anterp_huyck_scholarship']));   
$edward_raney_scholarship = trim(mysql_prep($_POST['edward_raney_scholarship']));
$school_type = trim(mysql_prep($_POST['school_type']));
$student_statement_consent_check_box = trim(mysql_prep($_POST['student_statement_consent_check_box']));
$guardian_statement_consent_check_box = trim(mysql_prep($_POST['guardian_statement_consent_check_box']));
$waiver = trim(mysql_prep($_POST['waiver']));



<input type="radio" name="student_gender" value="Male">Male<br>
<input type="radio" name="student_gender" value="Female">Female<br>
<select name="student_session_one_preference">
<option value="Session 1">Session 1: June 30 - July 21</option>
<option value="Session 2">Session 2: July 28 - August 18</option>
</select> <br/>

Preference 2:
<select name="student_session_two_preference">
<option value="Session 1">Session 1: June 30 - July 21</option>
<option value="Session 2">Session 2: July 28 - August 18</option>
</select>
<input type="checkbox" name="waldron_scholarship" value="Waldron Scholarship">Waldron Scholarship<br/>
<input type="checkbox" name="jesse_van_anterp_huyck_scholarship" value="Jesse Van Anterp Huyck Scholarship">Jesse Van Anterp Huyck Scholarship<br/>
<input type="checkbox" name="edward_raney_scholarship" value="Edward Raney Scholarship">Edward Raney Scholarship<br/>


<select name="school_type">
<option value="Public">Public</option>
<option value="Private">Private Parochial</option>
<option value="Other">Other</option>
</select>


<input type="radio" name="waiver" value="">I waive any right of access that I may have to information submitted by my referee<br>
<input type="radio" name="waiver" value="">I do not waive any right of access that I may have to information submitted by my referee<br>


<input type="checkbox" name="student_statement_consent_check_box" value="Agree">By checking this box, the student acknowledges <br/> that they have read the statement <br/> of consent and agrees with it.<br>


<input type="checkbox" name="guardian_statement_consent_check_box" value="Agree">By checking this box, the guardian acknowledges <br/> that they have read the statement <br/> of consent and agrees with it.<br>
```

Comment: have you tried placing your html tags inside a form element with method post?

Comment: Yes I did, I have everything inside of this. <form action="contact info.php" method="post">

Comment: I just do not know the easiest or proper way to store this type of form data (check boxes, radio buttons, drop down menus) in the database because I've never done it before

Answer (score 0):

can you try this code

```
<?php
    if(!empty($_POST) && isset($_POST["submit-btn"])){
        $gender = isset($_POST["student_gender"]) ? $_POST["student_gender"] : "";
        $student_session_one_preference = isset($_POST["student_session_one_preference"]) ? $_POST["student_session_one_preference"] : "";
        // do the rest of the elements

        echo $student_session_one_preference;
    }
?>


<form method="POSt">
<input type="radio" name="student_gender" value="Male">Male<br>
<input type="radio" name="student_gender" value="Female">Female<br>


<select name="student_session_one_preference">
                    <option value="Session 1">Session 1: June 30 - July 21</option>
                    <option value="Session 2">Session 2: July 28 - August 18</option>
                </select> <br/>
                Preference 2:
                <select name="student_session_two_preference">
                    <option value="Session 1">Session 1: June 30 - July 21</option>
                    <option value="Session 2">Session 2: July 28 - August 18</option>
                </select>


<input type="checkbox" name="waldron_scholarship" value="Waldron Scholarship">Waldron Scholarship<br/>
                    <input type="checkbox" name="jesse_van_anterp_huyck_scholarship" value="Jesse Van Anterp Huyck Scholarship">Jesse Van Anterp Huyck Scholarship<br/>
                    <input type="checkbox" name="edward_raney_scholarship" value="Edward Raney Scholarship">Edward Raney Scholarship<br/>


<select name="school_type">
                    <option value="Public">Public</option>
                    <option value="Private">Private Parochial</option>
                    <option value="Other">Other</option>
                </select>


<input type="radio" name="waiver" value="">I waive any right of access that I may have to information submitted by my referee<br>
                    <input type="radio" name="waiver" value="">I do not waive any right of access that I may have to information submitted by my referee<br>


<input type="checkbox" name="student_statement_consent_check_box" value="Agree">By checking this box, the student acknowledges <br/> that they have read the statement <br/> of consent and agrees with it.<br>


<input type="checkbox" name="guardian_statement_consent_check_box" value="Agree">By checking this box, the guardian acknowledges <br/> that they have read the statement <br/> of consent and agrees with it.<br>

<input type="submit" value="Submit" name="submit-btn">

</form>
```

this code assumes that the form submits to the same page.

Hope this helps you out.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15756139/need-help-storing-check-box-radio-button-and-drop-down-menu-data-in-mysql